# Inheritance and "is-A" relationship in Java

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the "is-A" relationship in Java and how it connects to interfaces.  Below I have declared an interface and a class that implements it to further clarify my question.

```
public interface Shape
{
   int method(Shape other);
}   

public class Circle implements Shape
{
   private Shape s = new Circle();   //line 1

   public int method(Shape other)    //line 2
   {
      return 3;
   }
}
```

So since `Circle` implements `Shape` we can say that `Circle` is-A `Shape` and therefore use a `Circle` object wherever a `Shape` is expected, just like `line1`.
However, when I write `public int methods(Circle other)` for `line2`, I get a compile time error saying that it cannot override the method in `Shape`.

Can someone please explain why the same logic does not apply to overriding the methods in interfaces. I mean a `Circle` is a `Shape` so why can't I just say `public int methods(Circle other)`.

Thank you

Comment: `int methods(Circle other) ` is different to `int method(Shape other)` which one do you mean?

Comment: I'm confused. There's no compile time error in this code.

Comment: Yes, there is NO compile time error.  But there will be if I substitute `int methods(Circle other)` for `int method(Shape other)`

Comment: And I dont understand why, because a `Circle` is a `Shape`

Comment: @odedsh why are they different?

Comment: Shape can be anything that implements the interface Shape. Circle can only be the specific class Circle (or anything that extends Circle). So these are two different methods that accept different types (and happen to overload the same name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Shape` interface specifies that instances of `Shape` *must* provide a method called `method` that takes *any Shape* as an argument. You can't override it with a method that takes *certain* shapes as an argument, because it doesn't satisfy the demands your interface requires. You can write another method called `method` that takes a `Circle` argument if you want, but it isn't overriding the method specified in the interface.

Put another way, the `Shape` interface says "Given any instance of `Shape`, I can call `method` on it and give it any other `Shape`." So your `Circle` class needs to define a matching `method` that takes *any Shape* as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Circle` is a `Shape`, but `Shape` is not necessarily a `Circle`!

Therefore, you can't implement `int method(Shape s)` as `int method(Circle c)`, because this method wouldn't accept other possible shapes, such as `Triangle implements Shape`.